# How to hide default save close option from a sharepoint list form which is customized by infopath

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, infopath, css, list-form

I am using an InfoPath form for a SharePoint list where I have placed two buttons to save and close the form.

SharePoint list form has its own default save close options on top. I want to remove or hide them. How can this be achieved?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: which sharepoint version you are using? do you have access to script editor or content editor webpart?

Comment: Sorry, I am not aware how to check the version. This SP was created via MS Teams and I can see Form web parts under customize list been disabled. :( is there any way I can achieve this? Thank you, Ganesh. :)

Comment: Do you have full permissions on SharePoint site?

Comment: Yes, I only created the site via MS Teams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you customize form for a list, customize form with InfoPath-> click on File -> Info -> Form Options->Uncheck the "Show InfoPath command in Ribbon or toolbar"checkbox,it will completely remove the ribbon, ->Save the changes and publish your form:

[image]

If you create a blank form, click on File -> Info -> Form Options->you can uncheck "save" and "Close" checkbox->Save the changes and publish your form:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, Lisa.. :-) It worked! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding below CSS on your list form page:

```
#Ribbon\.ListForm\.Edit\.Commit {
    display: none !important;
}
```